# What is this beautiful bush?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image][image]

Found this gorgeous bush at Port Orleans resort in Walt Disney World, but none of the employees knew what it was. Can anyone identify it for me?

Answer (score 5):

It's a [Queen's Wreath Vine](http://www.lavidaverde-greenhouse-nursery.com/climbing-vines.html), aka:  Purple Wreath, Bluebird Vine, Sandpiper Vine

> This native Central American flower, which blooms in the dry season, is striking in its unusual blue violet color.  Gracefully arched sprays of delicate flowers contrast with the crisp, sandpaper-like leaves.  The flowers are five deep purple petals about 2 cm across in the middle of five slender, blue or lavender sepals that create a distinctive star shape.  Although the flowers last only a few days, the star-like sepals in the cascading clusters persist for many days, gradually becoming lighter.  They are very attractive to butterflies.

[image]

Comment: I guessed them to be sepals from the picture op provided. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.